Spring Boot With Apache Camel Can't Not Send Full Logs to Zipkin
I'm using spring boot with apache camel and i need to view the travel of each request from camel to all microservices through zipkin but when i tried to connect apache camel to zipkin i can't see the full flow from camel to all microservice
Here is Pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app.ecommerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-integrations</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-integrations</name>
    <description>Product Service</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.6.0</org.mapstruct.version> <!-- map struct -->
        <maven.version>3.13.0</maven.version>
        <lombok.mapstruct.binding>0.2.0</lombok.mapstruct.binding>
        <open-api-doc.version>2.0.2</open-api-doc.version>
        <logbook.version>3.8.0</logbook.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.6.0</org.mapstruct.version> <!-- map struct -->
        <maven.version>3.13.0</maven.version>
        <lombok.mapstruct.binding>0.2.0</lombok.mapstruct.binding>
        <open-api-doc.version>2.0.2</open-api-doc.version>
        <camel.version>4.6.0</camel.version>
         <com.fasterxml.jackson.version>2.15.4</com.fasterxml.jackson.version>
    </properties>
    
    
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
       <!-- For Map Struct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>



       <!-- Apache Camel Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jacksonxml-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-xpath-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-file-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-springdoc-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>     
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-zipkin-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Zipkin and Micrometer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RabbitMQ Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-rabbitmq-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.mapstruct.binding}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

and application.yml is
spring:
  application.name: ecommerce-integrations
server:
  port: 8080
camel:
  servlet:
    mapping:
      context-path: /rest/ecommerce/api/v1/*
  springboot:
    tracing: true
  zipkin:
    endpoint: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
    host-name: localhost
    port: 9410
ecommerce:
  product-service:
    port: 9092
    host: localhost
    url: http://${ecommerce.product-service.host}:${ecommerce.product-service.port}/ecommerce/api/v1/products
  category-service:
    port: 9091
    host: localhost
    url: http://${ecommerce.category-service.host}:${ecommerce.category-service.port}/ecommerce/api/v1/categories
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.camel: TRACE
    org.apache.camel.zipkin: TRACE        # logging to see the zipkin traces
management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0  # to help zipkin and micrometer to export logs

and this is one of routes to find all categories in ecommerce app
package com.youssefgamal.ecommerce_integrations.camel.routes.categories;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;



@Component
public class FindAllCategoriesRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("direct:FindAllCategoriesRoute")
        .doTry()
            .routeId("FindAllCategoriesRoute")
            .to("direct:LogRequestRoute")
            .log("Before Calling Backend ==> BODY = ${body} , HEADERS = ${headers}")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethod.GET))
            .toD("{{ecommerce.category-service.url}}?bridgeEndpoint=true")
            .log("After Save Category ==> ${headers.id} ==> BODY = ${body} , HEADERS = ${headers}")
            .to("direct:LogResponseRoute")
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .to("direct:RestExceptionHandlingRoute")
        .end()
        ;
    }

}


I'm not sure, if your config works, as you're mixing camel versions in your pom.xml file. Anyways in the docu is mentioned, that you have to annotate your main class with @CamelZipkin. https://camel.apache.org/components/3.22.x/others/zipkin.html#camel-zipkin-camel-zipin-starter

when i annotate the class with @CamelZipkin , the idea tells me that the annotation is deprecated

Yes, because it actually is. That's why you probably have mixed the newer version with an older camel version. Try to annotate it with @CamelZipkin and use only camel version 3.22.2  in your pom.xml (not 4.6.0). Camel 3.22.x is the latest LTS version, which supports the component Zipkin.
